# Want to display error message if value increases max value in kendo numeric textbox

Tags: javascript, kendonumerictextbox

I have a kendo numeric textbox. I have set the Min value to that as 1 and Max value as 31.If I enter a value greater than 31 I want to display an error message that "value must be between 1 and 31".If You enter greater value the widget will round it to the max value. So if You enter a value of 50 with the keyboard and lose focus from the input or save the form, the value will be rounded to the max value of 31.

I want when You enter a greater value in the widget text box an error message to be displayed. Here is my code:

```
        @(Html.Kendo().NumericTextBox<int>()
        .Name("month_day_1")
        .Format("#")
        .Min(1)
        .Max(31)
        .Events(evnt => evnt.Change("Change"))
```

Can anyone please tell me how to Implement that.I tried to apply the condition on change event of kendo numeric textbox.But I got the error as  change is not defined on console.

Here is my javascript function:

```
    function Change(e) {
    debugger;
    var numerictextbox = $("#month_day_1").data("kendoNumericTextBox");
    var value = numerictextbox.value();

    if (value > 31) {
        alert("Month Day value must be between 1 and 31");
        return false;
    }
} 
      )
```

Comment: Insert a bigger max value or none at all and check the value yourself.

Comment: @Mouser.Sorry I did'nt get you.

Comment: Your code already checks for values larger than 31. Omit the max value and you'll be fine.

Comment: @Mouser ..It did'nt work..My numeric textbox is inside a kendo grid..Is it because of this reason Change event is not firing????

Answer (score 0):

This should do exactly what you need:

```
    @(Html.Kendo().NumericTextBox<int>()
    .Name("month_day_1")
    .Format("#")
    .Min(1)
    .Events(e => e.Change("ChangeInput"));

function ChangeInput(e) {
    var value = this.value;
    //This should work too
    //Using jQuery --> to use, delete value = this.value and uncomment the line below
    //var value = $("#month_day_1").val();

    if (value > 31) {
        alert("Month Day value must be between 1 and 31");
        return false;
    }
}
```

Since you are in a event called by the input itself, the keyword `this` refers to the input. Retrieving the value with `this.value` should work. Make sure your JavaScript is on the page and loaded.